# how can I make equations smaller in TeX?

Tags: latex, typesetting, equations

how can I make equations smaller in TeX? For example, I want to use the equation environment as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
long equation here
\end{equation}
```

but then it's displayed in a way that's too large to fit in the margin.  I get around this by using:

```
$ long equation here $
```

but then I don't get the automatic numbering and all the other nice features of equation environments.

secondly, how can I suppress equation numbering for specific equations in \begin{equation}\end{equation}? I'd like equations with no displayed numbers to not count to the total (so if the first 3 equations' numbers suppressed, but the 4th isn't, the 4th equation should be labeled "1").

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like the results you're getting from $ eqn $, you can get this by putting \textstyle in your equation environment.

To suppress numbering use "*":  `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`. You can also use \notag on individual equations in an environment (e.g. align).

Answer (score 3):

> but then it's displayed in a way that's too large to fit in the margin.

You're not trying to write the proof of Fermat's Last Lheorem, are you? :-)

Assuming you meant that the equation overflows to the margins, and also assuming you want to avoid that rather than change the font, I would suggest [amsmath](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).  For example, you can write a long equation like this:

```
\begin{multline}
  A = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\Delta x\left( a^{2}+\left( a^{2}+2a\Delta x
    +\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\right.\\
  +\left( a^{2}+2\cdot 2a\Delta x+2^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\\
  +\left( a^{2}+2\cdot 3a\Delta x+3^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\\
  + \ldots\\
  \left.+\left( a^{2}+2\cdot (n-1)a\Delta x +(n-1)^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right) \right)\\
  = \frac{1}{3}\left( b^{3}-a^{3}\right)
\end{multline}
```

(Example taken from [Mathmode](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/): a must if you want to typeset good math.) There are many other environments in amsmath: `align` and variations of it for aligning across lines, `gather` to gather multiple equations together, `multline` (note, no `i`) for a multi-line equation, `split`, etc.

To answer your second other question: you can get a non-numbered equation by using the starred form of the equation environment:

```
\begin{equation*}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  the multline approach does not work in my case though, because the sum I am trying to break up is actually in the numerator of a '\frac'.  i.e., i have something like:

\begin{multline}
\frac{Very long sum here that spans outside margins}{other sum}
\end{multline}

and the multline environment will not let me place "\\" in the numerator of \frac.  any ideas on how to break up such long equations inside frac?

Comment: Is your denominator short?  Maybe you can write your equation as (Numerator)(denominator)^{-1}, or (Numerator)/(denominator), or `\frac{part1}{denominator}+...+\frac{partN}{denominator}`.  I am not sure which is worse: not being able to use a nice `\frac{N}{D}` or using a small font only for one equation.

Comment: @user24837: Also, see pages 53 and 54 of Mathmode for examples of long fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Shall I understand it that `displaymath` environment (called by `equation` environment) typesets your math too wide but environment `math` (called by `$formulae$` fo example) typesets it right?

If so, there are commands that can switch its argument's `displaymath` mode to `math` mode and vice versa.

For inducing `math` style in `displaymath` you can use [`\textstyle{}`](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=699&start=0) command.
For inducing `displaymath` style in `math` you can use [`\displaystyle{}`](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/cookbook.html) command.

So for your task:

```
\begin{equation}\textstyle{
neverending formulae
}\end{equation}
```

I hope it will do what you want.